# How to cancel asynchronous read/write without closing the socket?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

How to cancel asynchronous read/write without closing the socket?
I use boost.asio.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [socket::cancel](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel.html).

> Cancel all asynchronous operations associated with the socket.

Comment: However, we note from the linked documentation:

* It will only cancel asynchronous operations that were initiated in the current thread.
* It can appear to complete without error, but the request to cancel the unfinished operations may be silently ignored by the operating system.

Comment: @SamLiddicott Please note that this applies only to CancelIo (Windows) , if enabled by BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_CANCELIO

Comment: @SamMiller That is such a relief! Thanks for clarifying!